# How do I connect to a SQL Server database server that IS NOT on localhost?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, amazon-web-services

The database I'm trying to connect to is on an AWS server and I'm trying to write a C# script that will pull data from the database. The only tutorials I can find are using localhost. Here's some code I tried:

```
static void Main()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(
                                   "user id=MyUsername;" +
                                   "password=MyPassword;" + 
                                   "server=MyServerName.ctf1qojvktpk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=MyDBName; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Need just a bit more information to be helpful!  What programming software are you using? (i.e. Visual studio, etc...)?  Are you creating a web app, MVC app, winform app?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm using Visual Studio and i'm currently trying to make a winform app!

Comment: can you reach the server the AWS server from where you run this code ? what about the security group and VPC for the database server ...

Comment: First thought is that I would try using string.format instead of the giant string concatenation  i.e. new SqlConnection(string.format("user id={0}, password={1}, server={2}, etc..", user, pass, server, etc...))

Comment: I've only been able to connect to the server and grab data from a PHP file that I wrote and ran on this computer. :/ I can't get it to connect at all using this C# code though. Also, I'm sorry, I don't understand the second part of your question! I'm super new to this

Comment: I'm also able to connect to the database using MySQL Workbench. Is there any way I could link Visual Studio to that?

Comment: I would try using the visual studio SQL connection wizard.  Depending on your version you can connect to a DB from VS and it'll assist you creating the appropriate connection string

Comment: So can I use that even though the DB is only connected to locally? The DB isn't on my actual local machine and it isn't popping up in the SQL connection wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a mySql database. You need to install the MySQL Connector for .NET.

Example connectionstring

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="server=myamazonserver.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;user id=rootusername;password=mypassword;database=mydatabasename; Convert Zero DateTime=True; Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Or in plain code

```
static void Main()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = 
       new SqlConnection(
            "server=myamazonserver.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;user id=rootusername;password=mypassword;database=mydatabasename; Convert Zero DateTime=True; Allow User Variables=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          );
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I currently have that, but I don't know how to connect to a DB that isn't on my machine.

Comment: I will edit it with an example connection string shortly

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I used that in an AWS project half a year ago. I have edited the server name, database name and login information.

Comment: What language is that in?

Comment: That's from a web.config.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a config file :/

Comment: Laura, you're just doing string concatenation, so you don't necessarily need the config file.  Just start the string with "server=myamazonserver.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com;"  in your SqlConnection constructor parameter.  Adjust that to whatever the path to your desired server is.

Comment: I just tried it and none of that worked. I changed the server, user id and password to my stuff, but I keep getting that there are unhandled exceptions with "Allow User Variables" and Convert Zero DateTime. Also, the providerName messed up the string because it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Remove 
      Convert Zero DateTime=True; Allow User Variables=True
and see if it helps